# Do I need a UK transit visa for flying to the Canary Islands?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I am planning to visit Tenerife, Canary Islands, Spain in October from Mumbai, India. I have already applied for a Spanish visa and am expecting to get it in two to three weeks.

I have booked a British Airways ticket. I will arrive at London Heathrow Airport, and my connection flight to Tenerife is from London Gatwick Airport. In-between there is a layover of seven hours. Therefore, will I need a transit visa for going to London Gatwick Airport from London Heathrow Airport?

If it is required, can I get it on arrival to London, or do I need to apply before starting the journey?

Further information:

I am an Indian citizen and I will have Spain Business visa for three weeks before starting the journey. This is my second visit to Spain.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to go through UK immigration to change airports. I am assuming you are an Indian citizen and don't have a European residence permit. In that case, [you will need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes). Merely holding a short-stay visa (which is required to enter Spain) is not enough to qualify for visa-free transit.

You won't be able to get this visa on arrival (in fact, you should be denied boarding by the airline in Mumbai and wouldn't even reach UK immigration).